# Another way to find subnet mask (java)?

Tags: java, android, networking, mask, subnet

Is there another way to find the `subnet mask` than:

```
String subnetMask="/"+networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0).getNetworkPrefixLength();
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the problem with this one?

Comment: i recieve the wrong mask: /-1 or /64. My one must be /24

Comment: JRE build 1.6.0_04-b12 had similar problem on Windows platform,
it looks like heritage of that at the first glance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665808/getnetworkprefixlength-returns-strange-subnet-mask