# How to get Wi-Fi subnet mask

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a way to show properly subnet mask.

I have tried with `DhcpInfo` but seems to be deprecated since API 18, so it is not a fix.

Also i have tried with:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221581/2535288

But gives me /::1%1%1/128 (it should be /192.168.1.2/24)

Thanks

**EDIT**:

[getNetworkPrefixLength() returns strange subnet mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665808/getnetworkprefixlength-returns-strange-subnet-mask)

This seems to be this problem.

Comment: if you looking for android have you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387036/how-to-get-gateway-and-subnet-mask-details-in-android-programmatically

Comment: @MayankPandya `DhcpInfo` is deprecated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221517/how-to-get-subnet-mask-using-java

Comment: Did you figure this out?